# What is the proper order of inclusion for these jQuery scripts?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

This is in an asp.net mvc3 view. The `@` markup is from the razor engine. Depending on the order of these scripts, different things occur. What is the proper order? This is the order I am currently using and it seems to work. If I change the order up errors start to show up.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" 
 type="text/javascript</script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" 
 type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"
 type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: i believe this is the correct order although i dont think it matters if the -ajax.js comes before or after the validate script files.  They are not dependent on each other

Comment: Having 2 `validate` scripts seems redundant.

Comment: @AymanSafadi - They are both required in asp.net mvc3.

Comment: The first validate is the official jQuery plugin.  The second is MS's add-ons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of validate and unobtrusive is unimportant, but both should come before validate.unobtrusive.  The code you've copied here is identical to the MVC3 template, suggesting that's the officially supported path.